# C++ Using files / semaphors to lock step processes / overhead-should I do this at all

Tags: c++, interprocess

I have a process A.
It has various scripts S1, S2, S3, S4, S5.

Previously process A merely calls script functions.
S1->tick(currentTime).

However, I would like to standardize the sandboxing of these scripts and move them all to external processes.

My question is:

1. What is the best portable C++ (linux/osx/win32) method to signal to subprocesses that a new tick dataset is available.
2. What is the best portable C++ way to make data available.

For instance, could I perhaps write data to a shared memory area (writable only by the primary process) and have the sub processes read from this memory area?

Would this be any faster than having some sort inter process communication?

Comment: Huh? If speed is important, why are you calling scripts? How often do ticks occur? What size and where is the new data set?

Comment: Speed is important, however scripting is equally important.  Currently ticks are 1/60th of a second (however adjustable).  The dataset can be minimal (message passing, XYZ positions/velocities/attributes of 100 objects), or substantial, locations of each triangle within a mesh of requested objects. ... I am looking for the best minimal overhead sandbox-able solution to provide scripts with information.  (Sandbox able in this case means that a script must not be able to "pollute" the primary processes data or other scripts' data)